# erlang on windows - stability end performance

Tags: erlang

how mature is erlang on windows platform? Is it production-ready? I saw that to compile erlang I need cygwin infrastructure - so I'm confused a bit how stable for example mnesia is ...

Thanks!

Comment: no experienced windows-erlang developer? :)

Answer (score 2):

Erlang works on Windows the same way, as on any other platform. It tries to be as "OS independent" as possible. For example `unix:cmd/1` was replaced by `os:cmd/1`. The OTP team maintains [instructions on how to build Erlang on Windows](http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL-WIN32.html).

When you make a pull request, it is built on various platforms, including Windows as stated in [their github README](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/172e812c491680fbb175f56f7604d4098cdc9de4/README.md).

Cygwin is also a mature project (started in 1995 according to Wikipedia), so it doesn't affect performance and stability.

You can even download [prebuilt packages for Windows](http://erlangcentral.org/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

Erlang is mature and stable. On Windows either on other supported OS'. You don't need to compile it from scratch, you can take precompiled binaries and use it.